# Tensorflow: Object Detection - tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:269] Master init: Unavailable: OS Error

Tags: tensorflow

I am tring to run object detection in distributed mode using https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/train.py 
The script supports distributed mode for google cloud. To use it on our cluster,I have set the TFCONFIG env varible in the script as follows

```
chief_host = ['host2:2229']
worker_hosts = ['host1:2230']
ps_hosts = ['host1:22231']
cluster = {'master': chief_host,
           'worker': worker_hosts,
           'ps': ps_hosts}
os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({'cluster': cluster,                                        
                                      'task': {'type': FLAGS.job_name, index': FLAGS.task_index}})                                

env = json.loads(os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG', '{}'))
```

I am run the training script using the below commands:

```
On host1:
python3 object_detection/train.py   --logtostderr --   pipeline_config_path=/home/.../faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config --train_dir=/home/.../modelOutput5th --job_name="ps" --task_index=0 --clone_on_cpu=true

On host2:
python object_detection/train.py   --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=/home/.../faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config --train_dir=/home/.../modelOutput5th --job_name="master" --task_index=0 --clone_on_cpu=true

On host1:
python3 object_detection/train.py   --logtostderr -- pipeline_config_path=/home/.../faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config --train_dir=/home/.../modelOutput5th --job_name="worker" --task_index=0 --clone_on_cpu=true
```

It launches the ps,master-worker and another worker fine. At times the training runs fine and proceed with the
training parallely, but at times it just fails with the below errors on the worker hosts.

```
 tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:269] Master init: 
 Unavailable: OS Error
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 
  'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnavailableError'>, OS Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 185, in <module>
tf.app.run()
  File "/home/sarmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 181, in main
worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/..../object_detection/trainer.py", line 377, in train
saver=saver)
  File "/home/...lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 746, in train
master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 1000, in managed_session
self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop
ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/home/...../training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/home/./python2.7/site-..packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 989, in managed_session
start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 726, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 281, in prepare_session
sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/..../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnavailableError: OS Error
```

Did not get any clue on what is the reason.Please help